# Having a copy of an object instead of a locked one

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking, copy

Is there a way of, instead of locking an object, show a temporary copy of it, to the one who is accessing it?

Comment: Not at that intrinsic level _I think_ you're asking about. I understand your need and believe that a modern functional language (maybe Clojure) might offer such modern and otherwise memory consuming methodologies at a very intrinsic level. I suggest you write yourself a constellation of immutable objects and make all sorts of variation constructors for them and that might be it. But you'll have to write them. .NET doesn't offer an out of the box solution for such a desire...

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the code that uses that object which in your case is a critical resource, with a TransactionScope and set the IsolationLevel to Snapshot.

That way, anyone trying to access the same object should see the value from before editing the object, until the transaction is complete.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid temporary copies if you use [volatile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x13ttww7%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) modifier.

> The system always reads the current value of a volatile object at the point it is requested, even if the previous instruction asked for a value from the same object. Also, the value of the object is written immediately on assignment.
>   The volatile modifier is usually used for a field that is accessed by multiple threads without using the lock statement to serialize access. Using the volatile modifier ensures that one thread retrieves the most up-to-date value written by another thread.